# Qualifier screen size small does not work for dimens

Tags: android

I am new to Android development and I am currently working on supporting different screen sizes and pixel densities for my app. Now, I have a button with the height `@dimen/button_height`.
In `dimens.xml` I have the following resource:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="button_height">55dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Now, I tried the app on different screen sizes and noticed, that, for example, on 3.3" WQVGA, the button is too big. This device is `240x400 px ldpi`, which is, `320x533 dp`.

I read [App resources overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) and [Support different Screen Sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) (I have to say that to me it is still not 100% clear how to support every devices configurations). According to that, the `screen-size` of this device is `small`, so I made another resource file `dimens.xml (small)` with

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="button_height">30dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Now, when I try this on the emulator, the button is still `55dp` high. So, what did I understand wrong? What would be a better approach to support smaller devices?

Comment: https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Answer (score 1):

Basically, 
Firstly understand the difference between px, dp,sp etc.

Prefer below link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2025541/6997819

1)
To support multiple screen sizes

You need to create

```
values-hdpi
values-xhdpi
values-xxhdpi
values-xxhdpi
```

> NOTE: I am suggesting four basic apart from above there are few more.

every values directory will have their own `dimen.xml` file

Suppose,

`dimen.xml` file inside `values-hdpi` have

```
<dimen name="button_height">55dp</dimen>
```

then in `dimen.xml` file inside `values-xhdpi` you should ideally increase the size

```
<dimen name="button_height">60dp</dimen>
```

Now, when you will execute the code the device will automatically pick based on their screen density.

2) Refer below link

https://github.com/intuit/sdp

This will ommit your above struggle.
The mechanism is same, but provided the gradle that will be easy to import and use as well.

Comment: I thought if I use dp, then mdpi, hdpi, ... don't make a difference?

Comment: dp is basically density pixel which differs screen by screen.

Comment: dp is density-independent-pixel. `To preserve the visible size of your UI on screens with different densities, you must design your UI using density-independent pixels (dp) as your unit of measurement. One dp is a virtual pixel unit that's roughly equal to one pixel on a medium-density screen (160dpi; the "baseline" density). Android translates this value to the appropriate number of real pixels for each other density.` -> From Android Developers

Comment: The link I have suggested on start, please go through it and also implement solution I have provided. Let me know does that helps you?

Comment: A device with a screen width of 320 dp can be hdpi as well as xhdpi. So using that as a qualifier qouldn't make a difference. The library you sugested would do the job, but what if I have to, for example, organize the structure of the layout in a completly different way on smaller screen sizes?

Comment: Please give it a try. It will make your understanding pretty clear. As this discussion will be much longer to carry on here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ssp](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) library to scale font size and [sdp](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) library to scale dimention size.